# What's the cost of additional data storage in Salesforce

Tags: data-storage, oem

I am trying to build an OEM app and would like to know what will be the additional cost org have to pay if they reach their 10 GB storage limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something you should talk to your (or your client's) Account Manager for, but...

From experience, let's just say that the cost is prohibitive. Salesforce doesn't really want customers using Sales/Service/Education/Health/etc clouds for general data storage. I don't recall any specific numbers, but a little digging turned up $125/mo for an extra 500MB.

Long story short, you'll want to look for other cloud data providers (Google, MS Azure, Amazon, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for the inside but data is data. It will grow with time.

Comment: It's technically cheaper to buy user licenses and get the free storage that comes with it, lol.

Comment: Can we move that data to big objects? Is there any limit applied there?

Comment: @itsaboutcode Your "data is data" comment doesn't make sense to me. I'm not saying that data X is different from data Y. I'm saying that _Salesforce doesn't want to store your data_. They need to offer _some_ data storage, but they don't want to be a data warehouse. The data growth strategy on Salesforce is "use someone other than us to store your data".

Comment: Your comment makes sense but what is salesforce if I have to save data outside of SF?

Comment: @itsaboutcode It's still a highly available, managed service that's able to be heavily customized through code and non-code tools. Not needing to worry about the system architecture, the network, or maintaining the underlying software packages is a big plus for a lot of people. You can still store ~5 million records in those 10GB (each record counts as 2kB towards that limit, regardless of how much data they actually contain. Some things like Emails take more).

Comment: @sfdcfox Not really. A user license only adds 20MB (Megabytes, not gigabytes) on top of the 10GB. You can have 100 users paying $12,500 per month and only get 12GB of data storage. Absolutely absurd.